# How do I approach this question

Tags: summation

[image]

From my search the summation cyc denote summations over permutations. But now there's a set involved, and I feel quite lost on how to put the meaning of it all together and how to proceed.

Comment: The summation cyc denotes summation over the cyclic permutations, where you rotate $x,y,z$ around the circle.  Have you tried the hint?  Write out the three terms in the cyclic sum, put them over a common denominator, and see what happens.  I am sure you will find some nice simplification.

Comment: So, now what's a cyclic permutation? Is it the thing after the equal sign in part ii)?

Comment: That gives a definition, which is the usual one.  If you have a triplet $(x,y,z)$ the cyclic sum includes $(x,y,z),  (y,z,x), (z,x,y)$.  It works for longer sequences, too.